# Is there a way to create pixel centroids inside polygons with PostGIS ?

Tags: qgis, postgis, centroids

I am trying to find a solution to do the function of the QGIS-tool 'Generate points(pixel centroids) inside polygons' in PostGIS.

In the picture below you can see the output. Is there a way to do it in PostGIS?

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ST_PixelAsCentroids](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsCentroids.html):

> Returns the centroid (point geometry) for each pixel of a raster band
>   along with the value, the X and the Y raster coordinates of each
>   pixel.

Example:

```
create table centroids as(
SELECT x, y, val, ST_AsText(geom), geom
    FROM (SELECT dp.* FROM someraster, LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1) AS dp) foo
    join somepolygon
    on st_intersects(foo.geom, somepolygon.wkb_geometry)
    where somepolygon.id=328045)
```

[image]